# consolidating data with fixed columns but variable rows from many worksheets to one

Tags: excel, vba, multidimensional-array, copy

Hi I am ne w to excel VBA and getting by using loads of help online. I need to copy data with changing number of rows from multiple worksheets to a single worksheet starting at cell H4. The data columns are fixed. I don't need an empty row between the data in the destination worksheet. I have 20 source worksheets to transfer. My code so far for each worksheet copies the destination sheet using arrays. Also I am not sure how to make all the sheets copy in one operation.

```
Sub Adam_to_array()

    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Sheet8.Range("P3").CurrentRegion.value
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    Next i
    Sheet100.Range("H4").CurrentRegion.ClearContents
    Dim rowCount As Long, columnCount As Long
    rowCount = UBound(arr, 1)
    columnCount = UBound(arr, 2)
    Sheet100.Range("H4").Resize(rowCount, columnCount).value = arr
    
End Sub

Sub Paul_to_array()

    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Sheet7.Range("P4").CurrentRegion.value
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    Next i
  
    Dim rowCount As Long, columnCount As Long
    rowCount = UBound(arr, 1)
    columnCount = UBound(arr, 2)
    Sheet100.Range("H").Resize(rowCount, columnCount).value = arr
```

Comment: What is your `i` loop for? You'd be better off with a single procedure with a worksheet argument than separate ones for each sheet.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, as i mentioned I am new to vba I thought the i loop was for reading the data in source sheet. I will try using your suggested approach.

Comment: The `arr` line writes the data to the array. Your loop does nothing as there's nothing in it.

Comment: Just curious, (1) is your CurrentRegion to each sheet (which need to be copied to sheet100) not consistent ? As in Adam sub, the current region of sheet8 is P3 ... and in Paul sub, the current region of sheet7 is P4. Please CMIIW. (2) In what cell of Sheet100 do you want to put the result from Paul sub after running Adam sub ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly and if it's OK with you that the sub is not using array .... below is the example data, table with 5 columns header :

[image]

x1 = the data in sheet "Sheet1"
x2 = the data in sheet "Sheet2"
x3 = the data in sheet "Sheet3"
The header starts in cell A1 on each sheet.

If your expected result in sheet "Output" is like this :
[image]

then the sub:

```
Sub test()
Dim ColStart As Long: Dim i As Long
Dim rg As Range: Dim oFill As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet

ColStart = 8

For Each sh In Sheets
    If sh.Name <> "Output" Then
        Set rg = sh.UsedRange
        Set rg = rg.Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1, rg.Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)

        For i = 1 To rg.Columns.Count
            Set oFill = Sheets("Output").Cells(Rows.Count, ColStart - 1 + i).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            If Application.CountA(rg.Columns(i)) <> 0 Then _
                rg.Columns(i).Cells.SpecialCells(xlConstants).Copy Destination:=oFill
        Next i
    End If
Next sh

End Sub
```

Before running the sub, make a new sheet, name it "Output", and put all the columns header starting in cell H3.

There are two loops
A. Loop to each sheet which name is not "Output"
(The sub assumed that all the rest of the existing sheets in the workbook other than sheet "Output" is where the data need to be copied to sheet "Output").

B. Loop to each column of the existing data in the looped sheet.

In loop-A, it set the data range of the looped sheet into variable rg.

In loop-B (loop to each column in rg variable), it set where the last blank row (of the respected column in sheet "Output") into oFill variable, check if the looped column has data then copy the cell which has value in the looped column of the rg and paste it to oFill cell.